# ютуб и php, вставка ролика

Tags: php, youtube

Есть некий массив, который достается из базы.

```
$a = 'текст
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2B-nbLVqDjY
еще текст {smiles} ';
```

Нужна функция, которая будет искать в масиве ссылку на ютуб, брать индефикатор и заменять ссылку на

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2B-nbLVqDjY" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

перерыл пол гугла, ничего толкового не нашел.
help )

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос, пожалуйста пометьте его зеленой галкой под стрелками для голосования.

Comment: @Anamnian, пишет, что можно только через 2 дня.

Answer (score 2):

Сам спросил,сам написал))
пользуйтесь на здоровье :)

```
function video($str) {
$str = preg_replace('#(^|\s|\(|\])((https?://)?www\.youtube\.com/watch\?(.*?&)*v=([^ \r\n\t`\'"<]+))(,|\[|<|\s|$)#iuU', '\1<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/\5?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>\6', $str);
        return $str;
    }
```

Comment: Вы можете пометить собственный ответ как решение (зеленая галочка), чтобы не оставлять вопрос открытым (ну и рейтинг получите заодно)